# Replace all instances of * with \cdot only in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

As i understand the most accepted form to write the multiplication symbol in
LaTeX in `\cdot`. However i have a rather large document already with `*` as the 
multiplication operator. 
I would like to replace all instances of `*` with `\cdot`, but only in 
mathmode(`$ Math $`) and displaymathmode (`$$ display math $$`).
I would like to do this with future documents as well, as i think it improves
readability of the code.

Is there a way to do this with `xstring` for example? Or any other way to do this for the whole document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As an unrelated note, you shouldn't be using double dollar signs for displayed math, see e.g. [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ ... $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854)

Comment: I'd say this is a job for your editor programme. Not LaTeX as you basically cannot ask LaTeX to first run the entire doc through `xstring`. Also remember that in many cases the multiplication dot can be ignored.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to replace all occurrences using the find&replace functionality that almost every text editor provides. If your code is really well written, replacing the string ` * ` (with spaces!) _might_ be sufficient, as this would not destroy starred commands.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`\cdot` is defined by

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cdot}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"01}
```

So you just need to put this in your preamble

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{*}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"01}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you insist on not changing the body of your source, you could make `*` math-active

```
\documentclass{article}
\mathcode`\*="8000 %
{\catcode`\*=\active\gdef*{\cdot}}
\begin{document}

  Here we have some asterisks: * * * * *

  Now we some some mathematics: $a*b*c$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: David's answer is more elegant, of course :-)

Comment: But your's should work with plain-tex too :)

Comment: @JosephWright could you explain the difference between your approach and the David's one? Thank you

Comment: @soundwave I've made `*` active and simply replaced it by `\cdot` in a math mode context. David has used the TeX math symbol machinery to do the replacement 'later'.

Comment: @JosephWright thank you! so do the asterisks defined in the two ways behave in the same way? that is, by writing `*` in math mode the symbol `\cdot` is shown, while outside math mode by writing `*` it is shown the asterisk symbol